# Failed to execute script fbs_pyinstaller_hook for pyqt5 gui application

Tags: python, compilation, pyqt5, fbs

I'm trying to build my python pyqt5 gui application for windows, after running:

```
fbs startproject

fbs freeze
```

using pyinstaller I get also the same results
this is my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
               ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\bitsapp37\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\bitsapp37\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\bitsapp37\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\Qt5Widgets.dll', '.')
              ]
a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\bitsapp37\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\add.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\contact.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\config.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\import.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\settings.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\exit.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\delete.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\export.png', '.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\help.png', '.'),
             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=['c:\\users\\jared\\docume~1\\python~1\\bitsap~1\\bitsap~1\\lib\\site-packages\\fbs\\freeze\\hooks'],
             runtime_hooks=['C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\target\\PyInstaller\\fbs_pyinstaller_hook.py'],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=True , 
          icon='C:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Bits App\\icon5.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

then trying to run the executable file in target folder, I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this, or what might be causing it?

If it helps im using python 3.7

Edit: I tried python 3.6 and reinstalling everything, still getting the same error.

Edit 2:
error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "target\PyInstaller\fbs_pyinstaller_hook.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbs_runtime'
[16452] Failed to execute script fbs_pyinstaller_hook
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue, or it seems to be the issue, apparently pyinstaller didnt install all the way, when I looked at the github, I noticed pyinstaller-hooks which is what I installed, then it worked, so be sure to:

```
pip install pyinstaller-hooks
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I get `Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (20200804)` after this command which means I have that package but I still get the questions error. here is my <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244980/failed-to-execute-script-fbs-pyinstaller-hook">question</a>. please take a look.