# Failed to execute script fbs_pyinstaller_hook

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5, fbs

I'm trying to create an executable file from the my PyQt5 application. my system specs:

- ubuntu 18.04
- python (3.6.9)
- fbs (0.8.9)
- matplotlib (3.3.0)
- numpy (1.19.1)
- pandas (1.1.0)

I'm following [fbs tutorial](https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial) to build a executable file from my application. I run the application without error with `fbs run` command.

The `fbs freeze` command produce this output:

```
-c:12: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg backend was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
Done. You can now run `target/DataVisualization/DataVisualization`. If
that doesn't work, see https://build-system.fman.io/troubleshooting.
```

But I'm importing version `5` of  `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg` in my code as:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
```

when I run the executable file from

> ~/MyProject/target/AppName

I get this error:

```
./AppName 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fbs_pyinstaller_hook.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbs_runtime'
[1331] Failed to execute script fbs_pyinstaller_hook
```

I have checked the solutions given in these links, but none of them came handy!

- [The most common mistake](https://build-system.fman.io/troubleshooting#:~:text=Failed%20to%20execute%20script%20fbs_pyinstaller_hook,the%20tutorial%20for%20an%20example.)
- [Failed to execute script fbs_pyinstaller_hook for pyqt5 gui application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479154/failed-to-execute-script-fbs-pyinstaller-hook-for-pyqt5-gui-application)

Any ideas of what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entirely gave up using FBS.. pyinstaller works very well for compiling PyQt5 code.. try using just pyinstaller and see if that works.

Comment: now I get another error: `NameError: name 'defaultParams' is not defined` `Failed to execute script main` is it my code which has error or something else is the problem?

Comment: when compiling to pyinstaller just do `pyinstaller -F main.py` Then open up the command prompt or terminal and run the file there so you read the error with more information.

Comment: it is the error now: `NameError: name 'defaultParams' is not defined`. should I update question?

Comment: somewhere you didn't define that in your code.. Is that a library? or a variable?

Comment: no one, its a `pyinstaller` issue. I found my answer [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18180)

Comment: Great! Awesome! Maybe write a new a answer and explain your solution.